# Is there a way to refresh only first N rows of MATERIALIZED VIEW PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I have a materialized view in PostgreSQL and when it's refreshing even without updates it takes around 5 seconds.

The case is that not stale data is only the first 5 rows, they changing and sometimes there is a new row appears on top. So all other rows are stable and will never change.
I'm wondering is there a way to do it.

Comment: Not with materialized views, no.

Comment: 5 seconds is not bad at all. You can cron that execution to refresh the view automatically every hour or so. Shouldn't be an issue. Now, if you want to refresh every minute or on every insert, then you have a design problem.

Comment: @TheImpaler It needs to be refreshed every 30 seconds or so. Now I'm wondering maybe I should create another small materialized view and refresh a smaller one every 30 seconds. And then the query will union small view and big stale view, which will be updated only if there is a new row in a small view inserted (which is once in 15 minutes). Is this a good solution?

Comment: If your materialized view basically contains historic data that does not change then you could refresh the view every night and when using the data just append info from current date: `SELECT date, sum FROM materialized_sales UNION SELECT date, sum(sum) FROM sales WHERE date= current_date;`

Comment: @karambaq Refreshing every 30 s is not the intended use case for a materialized view. As you say, maybe you can separate the view into an historic one refreshed every night + a recent one (maybe the last 24 hours only) that is refreshed every minute or so. With the right indexes that refresh should be fast.